# I don't understand this QuerySnapshot thing and I need to get a List of map from it to turn it into a List of Object

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get a List<Map<String,dynamic>> and turn it into a List of Item objects.
Here's where I reached so far

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:htu_app/models/item.dart';

class categoryCubit extends Cubit<List<Item>> {
  categoryCubit() : super([]);

  Future<void> getItemsFromCategory({required String category}) async {
    QuerySnapshot docs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where('category', isEqualTo: category)
        .get();
  }
}
```

Here's a pic of a document may it help you understand what I'm trying to achieve

[Document example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PVOj.png)

And here's the object im working with.

```
class Item {
  Item(
      {required this.name,
      required this.price,
      required this.category,
      required this.date,
      required this.pic});

  String name;
  double price;
  String category;
  String date;
  String pic;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
      name: json['name'],
      price: json['price'],
      category: json['category'],
      date: json['json'],
      pic: json['pic']);
}
```

I've been looking around for a while and haven't gotten a full answer to it and I'm very new to firestore collections so please help me quick if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  Future<void> getItemsFromCategory({required String category}) async {
    final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items')
        .where('category', isEqualTo: category)
        .get();
    emit(result.docs.map((e) => Item.fromJson(e.data())).toList());
  }
```